# adding new Colums at Query editor from Table

Tags: database, merge, powerbi

Im new in the PowerBI section and i need some help.

what i did so far is to Merge Queries from two tables and now i got one table with the new coulmn "ROUTE DATA" (like in the picture below)

and in each row theres Table (i opened one of the tables like you can see in the picture)

so I dont know how to create a new coulmns for each ID for every row in the Table. like you can see in the pictures (the red cells i added).

[image]
hope you can help me with it.

Thanks Daniel.

EDIT SUNDAY 6/10/18 : @Marc Pincince
Marc thank you very much!! so the problem now is the cells with null value:
my comment to your post: (Hello Marc. again thank you! so I tried following your instructions and the last one is not working so well. I will add a picture to show you whats wrong with it but I cant add the pictures to here so I will add them to the main post sorry for bothering you. the problem is all the "null" cells. can i remove them and get only the data? image.ibb.co/cHncHo/Capture.png and image.ibb.co/c4prco/Capture1.png)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***---The original answer appears first, followed by an updated version based on discussion---***

Here's a possible approach...

Starting with this:[image]

Do what @Alexis suggested: click the expand icon in the upper right of the ROUTE DATA column and choose to expand all of the columns (*Select All Columns*) and click OK:

[image]

Yes, you'll see all four rows expanded:

[image]

Now, select the ROUTE NAME, START TIME, AND COMPLETE TIME columns and then click the *Transform* tab, then the *Unpivot Columns drop-down arrow* and *Unpivot Only Selected Columns*:

[image]

You'll see something like this:

[image]

Now, add an index column by clicking the *Add Column* tab and *Index Column*. The index should start with zero and look like this.

[image]

Now add a modulo. You do that by selecting the index column and clicking the *Add Column* tab, then *Standard*, then *Modulo*, then type `3` and click OK.

[image]

You should see something like this:

[image]

Now add a custom column by clicking the *Add Column* tab and then *Custom Column*; just keep the column name as `Custom`, type `[Attribute] & " " & Text.From(([Index]-[Modulo])/3)` into the formula box, and click OK. This creates unique column names, which you will need for your new columns in a moment:

[image]

[image]

And remove the Attribute, Index, and Modulo columns by selecting them all and then the *Home* tab, and then *Remove Columns*.

[image]

[image]

Now select the Custom column and then click the *Transform* tab and then *Pivot Column*:

[image]

And then select Value for the *Values Column* entry, click on *Advanced options* and then the *drop-down arrow* to select *Don't Aggregate*, and click OK. You should see something like this:

[image]

Here's the M code from Advanced Editor:

```
let
Source = QuerySource,
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "ROUTE DATA", {"UTID", "ROUTE NAME", "START TIME", "COMPLETE TIME"}, {"UTID", "ROUTE NAME", "START TIME", "COMPLETE TIME"}),
#"Unpivoted Only Selected Columns" = Table.Unpivot(#"Expanded Custom", {"ROUTE NAME", "START TIME", "COMPLETE TIME"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Unpivoted Only Selected Columns", "Index", 0, 1),
#"Inserted Modulo" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Modulo", each Number.Mod([Index], 3), type number),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Modulo", "Custom", each [Attribute] & " " & Text.From(([Index]-[Modulo])/3)),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Attribute", "Index", "Modulo"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Custom]), "Custom", "Value")
in
#"Pivoted Column"
```

***---UPDATED PER DISCUSSION---***

Starting with: [image]

And expanding it to...

[image]

Select the ROUTE NAME, START TIME, AND COMPLETE TIME columns and then click the *Transform* tab, then the *Unpivot Columns* drop-down arrow and *Unpivot Only Selected Columns* as before:

[image]

Now, select the UTID column and then the *Transform* tab, then *Group by*, and set up the dialog box like this and click OK:

[image]

You'll see something like this:

[image]

Click the *Add Column* tab and then *Custom Column* and set it up like this:

[image]

Then expand the new Custom column to see something like this:

[image]

Then add another custom column (*Add Column* tab > *Custom Column*) set up like this:

[image]

You should see something like this:

[image]

Expand the Records in the Custom.1 column. It should look something like this:

[image]

Click on the Custom column and then the *Add Column* tab and the *Standard button's dropdown arrow*, and pick *Modulo*. Type `3` and click OK. You'll see something like this:

[image]

Add another custom column, set up like this:

[image]

You should see something like this:

[image]

Remove the columns you don't want anymore (i.e., Count, AllData, Custom, UTID.1, Attribute, and Modulo) to get to something like this:

[image]

Then click on column Custom2 and then the *Transform* tab and *Pivot Column*, and then select Value for the *Values Column* entry, click on *Advanced options* and then the *drop-down arrow* to select *Don't Aggregate*, and click OK. You should see something like this:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
let
Source = QuerySource,
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "ROUTE DATA", {"UTID", "ROUTE NAME", "START TIME", "COMPLETE TIME"}, {"UTID", "ROUTE NAME", "START TIME", "COMPLETE TIME"}),
#"Unpivoted Only Selected Columns" = Table.Unpivot(#"Expanded Custom", {"ROUTE NAME", "START TIME", "COMPLETE TIME"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Only Selected Columns", {"UTID"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}, {"AllData", each _, type table}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each {0..[Count]-1}),
#"Expanded Custom1" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom"),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Custom1", "Custom.1", each [AllData]{[Custom]}),
#"Expanded Custom.1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Custom.1", {"Column1", "UTID", "Attribute", "Value"}, {"Column1", "UTID.1", "Attribute", "Value"}),
#"Inserted Modulo1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Custom.1", "Modulo", each Number.Mod([Custom], 3), type number),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Modulo1", "Custom2", each [Attribute] & " " & Text.From(([Custom]-[Modulo])/3)),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Count", "AllData", "Custom", "UTID.1", "Attribute", "Modulo"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Custom2]), "Custom2", "Value")
in
#"Pivoted Column"
```

Comment: first of all thank you very much for your concern. Im not at work right now so i will try this tomorrow ASAP and then i will let you know :) thanks!!

Comment: Hello Marc. again thank you! so I tried following your instructions and the last one is not working so well. I will add a picture to show you whats wrong with it but I cant add the pictures to here so I will add them to the main post sorry for bothering you. the problem is all the "null" cells. can i remove them and get only the data? https://image.ibb.co/cHncHo/Capture.png and https://image.ibb.co/c4prco/Capture1.png

Comment: Daniel, You have so many nulls because of the way you are formatting this with a separate, distinct set of new columns for each UTID. Since one UTID's new columns don't apply to the others', those others' cells will show nulls. Having said that, will your ROUTE DATA tables always have exactly four routes? If so, you could stack the routes info in your table, so route 0 info for each UTID appears in the same column and route 1 info for each UTID appears in the same column, etc. (Each UTID would have only 12 associated route columns--3 for each route: _name, start time, and complete time_.)

Comment: hey Marc, and no, for I cant tell how many routes I will have for different UTID. some UTID can have 3,4,5 and even 6 routes. I thought to merge the columns but because the number of routes for every UTID is deference I cant do that. Do you know how I can fix it? maybe there's a way to move the ROUTE DATA to the 7 columns for every UTID no matter what's the route data I have there?

Comment: i have something like 12 routes in total but thats not mean that for every UTID all the routes need to be exists. do you know how can i fix that?

Comment: I provided an update to my answer, which I think might help.

Comment: thank you for helping me! I will try this in two days, sorry just got vacation from work and the data is there :) I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Click that expand icon in the top right corner of the table and choose which rows you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but thats not what i need because if i will do that i will get 4 rows for the same ID.(you can see that rows at the table) i would like to have those 4 rows at the table below in the big table but in only one row. i want to get only 1 row with 1 ID (UNIQUE)

Comment: Which row from the table do you want then? Is it always the `PreFI` one?

Comment: i want all of the rows from the table. PREFI, PACKING, UNPACKING,CA to be in one row. so i mean because i have 4 coulmns in every row i will get 12 more coulmns in one row.